# (psql) How to sum up on a column based on conditions?

Tags: postgresql

I have a following postgresql table.

| user | amount | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| danny | 2 | deposit |
| danny | 3 | withdraw |
| kathy | 4 | deposit |
| kathy | 5 | deposit |
| kathy | 6 | withdraw |

Now, I am trying to get every user's remaining wallet balance. The sum up calculation works like this: for deposits they are positive in the sum function and for withdraw they are negative values. e.g. For danny, the remaining balance after 2 deposit and 3 withdraw is 2 - 3 = -1. For kathy, the remaining balance is 4 + 5 - 6 = 3.

What is the easiest way to calculate this in one Postgresql query?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `SUM`, `GROUP BY` and `CASE WHEN`

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `type` from text to the numeric factor 1 or -1 as appropriate. Then just do `sum(amount * factor)`:

```
with test (usr, amount, type) as 
     ( values ( 'danny', 2, 'deposit')
            , ( 'danny', 3, 'withdraw')
            , ( 'kathy', 4, 'deposit')
            , ( 'kathy', 5, 'deposit')
            , ( 'kathy', 6, 'withdraw')
     )
-- your query starts here
select usr                   "User"
     , sum (amount * factor) "Balance"
  from ( select usr
              , amount
              , case when type = 'deposit'  then  01 
                     when type = 'withdraw' then -1
                     else null 
               end factor
          from test
       ) sq 
 group by usr 
 order by usr;
```

**NOTE:** It is poor practice to use `user` as an identifier (i.e. column name, etc) since it is both a Postgres and SQL standard [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).